# Redactor field removing P tags

Tags: redactor

Firstly, I used WP Export All / Feed Me to migrate blog posts from a wordpress site to a craft site. The HTML from the wordpress content field has all been imported properly. Text is wrapped in p tags, headers in heading tags etc etc. However, even though the P tags are present in the html version of the redactor editor, on the page the p tags seem like they are stripped. I'll attach images to show what I mean.

This is my code in the redactor field.

```
<p>Just a quick update on a large fit out project we are undertaking in Castle Donington to allow two companies to move into the space.</p>
<p>The majority of the first fix M&E has been completed and we are currently installing the framework to allow the toughened glass walls to be installed. As you can see from the photos, this is a high specification project that is going to completely transform the space, and create a modern and clean office environment.</p>
```

This is my code for displaying the redactor field

```
{% if entry.type == 'blog' %}
            <div class="container mx-auto blog-post w-full my-4 {{block.customTextClass}} text-block text-{{block.position.value}}">
                {{ block.text }}
            </div>
{% else %}
```

[image: image displaying the outputted html]

Any help with this would be massively appreciated. Right now a workaround I have found is to delete the text, save the entry, then re-add the text and save. When I do this the p tags remain.

Comment: Strange, can you try to run `./craft resave/entries` ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/console-commands.html#resave-entries)) and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately this didn't work. From what I can tell I have to actually change some text in the field and save it, and then the <p> tags get saved into the database. Very very weird.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this at all? Issue is also listed here: https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/669

Comment: I didn't, I tried for a while but ended up just having to do it manually. @MalcolmMaclean